# Want to set label value on TeeChart InnerTick VC++

Tags: activex, teechart

I wanted to set label text value on TeeChart InnerTick using VC++. like we have below example (I wanted to set AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD values).

// Sorry i was not able to attach image.

Below mention chart we have created using CGraph. to get co-ordinates we are using SDKInfo property. i wanted to know that how can we get all these x axis,y axis values using TeeChart. Is there any API to get these co ordinates ?

1
 X axis max (your data units)

2
 X axis min (your data units)

3
 Y axis max (your data units)

4
 Y axis min (your data units)

5
 X axis length (Graphics Server view units)

6
 Y axis length (Graphics Server view units)

7
 X origin (Graphics Server view units)

8
 Y origin (Graphics Server view units)

9
 Label font size (percentage of system font)

|
|
|         AAAA                 BBBB                CCC                DDDD 
|__________|____________________|___________________|__________________|________
           |                    |                   |                  |
          111                 222                  333               444

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using TeeChart .NET or TeeChart ActiveX?

Comment: I am using TeeChart ActiveX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about what exact TeeChart version are you using so this answer may be a bit vague.

All binary installations of TeeChart come with a program we call "Features Demo". This program includes examples showing how to use the majority of features supported.
One of the examples is the "Custom Labels", you should find it under "All Features\Welcome !\Axes\Labels\Custom Labels" in the program.

Also, to convert axis values to screen pixels, all TeeChart versions provide "Calc*" functions for it. Ie, to convert the value 10 in the bottom axis to pixels, in TeeChart ActiveX:

```
XPix = tChart1.Axis.Bottom.CalcXPosValue(10);
```

Just note these functions need the chart to be drawn once so the internal properties have been initialized and the calculations can be correctly done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am using TeeChart Pro Activex 2014. I wanted to add text just above inner tick in bottom axis. i am not able to get position of first inner tick inside chart.                                                                                   i am using below mention code to display text inside chart but it is also not working.  inside OnOnAfterDrawTchart function m_nAxisBottom = m_ctrlChart.GetAxis().AddCustom(FALSE);
 CAxis axisBottom = m_ctrlChart.GetAxis().GetCustom(m_nAxisBottom);
 long lRet1 = axisBottom.GetLabels().Add((dXAxisMinimum + dXAxisMaximum) / 2, "AAAA");

Comment: Here you are using Custom Axes, not Custom Labels. Try with m_ctrlChart.GetAxis().GetLeft().GetLabels().Add((dXAxisMinimum + dXAxisMaximum) / 2, "AAAA");

Comment: Thanks yeray, I have used your suggestion to display text, with that i am able to display the label text below the graph bottom axis. but I am unable to display text inside Chart area (i.e. above the graph bottom axis).

Comment: You move the bottom axis a bit up m_ctrlChart.GetAxis().GetBottom.SetPositionPercent(10); Or you can use Annotation tools. Or you can draw your text directly on the canvas as OnAfterDraw event